# Flutter Webrtc - 3 Peer connection

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc

I am creating a 3 peer Webrtc Flutter app. I have used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wWOyaJ-PUM, this example to learn. but I don't know how to create 3 Peer connections?

I am also using node socket.io for creating a room.  But still don't get it How to use RTCPeerConnection to make 3 peer video chat in Flutter? I already asked on Reddit. But not get a relevant reply. so please give me any relevant steps or code?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to either

- setup peer-to-peer between all the parties (there will be 3 links in total, each party will be sending video twice and be receiving two streams), or
- you need an intermediary server